# Virtual robot speed reduce when approaching to corner

Tags: ros, rviz, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone

I has a problem related to my simulation, I am currently running a simulation on teb_local_planner.

When I run my simulation, I found out that my robot become very slow in situation that have to go around the corner.

like this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bf8igGb1U_M

here is my paste bin for the teb_local_planner_param.yaml file http://pastebin.com/7VVJ0kSL

It report warning like below

```
[ WARN] [1473995722.552885072, 92.600000000]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.6000 seconds
[ WARN] [1473995723.131613002, 93.100000000]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.5000 seconds
[ WARN] [1473995723.132625078, 93.100000000]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.5000 seconds
[ WARN] [1473995724.218327309, 94.200000000]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 1.1000
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243866/virtual-robot-speed-reduce-when-approaching-to-corner/) by [samping](https://answers.ros.org/users/26715/samping/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can you try to check if the issue still occurs with the most recent version in the [kinetic-devel](https://github.com/rst-tu-dortmund/teb_local_planner) branch? you can also compile it on indigo.

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2016-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [samping](https://answers.ros.org/users/26715/samping/) on 2016-09-26**:
Thank you very much croesmann, do you mind put your comments in answer so I can close this post?